# Determine if the set of all circulant matrices is an F-subalgebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

**Question:** Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $F$ be a field. A matrix in $M_{n \times n} (F)$ of the form given below is called a circulant matrix. Determine if the set of all circulant matrices in $M_{n \times n} (F)$ is an F-subalgebra of $M_{n \times n} (F)$.
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a_{1} & a_{2} & ... & a_{n} \\
        a_{n} & a_{1} & ... & a_{n-1} \\
        . & . & ... & .\\
        a_{2} & a_{3} & ... & a_{1}\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I understand that an F-subalgebra is a subspace that is closed under vector multiplication, and that it is already considered closed under addition and scalar multiplication because it is a subspace.

I also believe that because this matrix is $n \times n$, it is considered a square matrix which means that it is an associative unital $F$-algebra.

However, I have no idea how to go about proving this problem...Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: letting

$$C=\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 &... & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 &... & 0\\
        \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
        0 & 0 & 0 &... & 1\\
        1 & 0 & 0 &... & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

(with property $C^n=I$),

the general formula you have given for circulant matrices becomes:

$$a_1I+a_2C+a_3C^2+ \cdots +a_nC^{n-1}.$$

Comment: Im sure your hint should make it simple, but Im still not understanding.  The general formula you give is for the set of all circulant matrices, correct? Then how do I show that that is a subalgebra?

Comment: The fact that a circulant matrix is nothing else than a polynomial in $C$ (of any degree because, due to property $C^n=I$, all polynomials in $C$ can be brought back to a degree $<n$) provides a very simple proof of stability for matrix multiplication ($\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2 \in M_{n \times n}(F)\Rightarrow \Gamma_1\Gamma_2\in M_{n \times n}(F)$)

Comment: You can also view that as a consequence of Cayley-Hamilton. Multiplying the characteristic polynomial (which A satisfies) with A will let you write $A^{n+1}$ as linear combination of the lower powers and you can iterate that idea to as high a power you want.

Comment: @mathreadler It will not do the same thing, i.e., warrant that the product of matrices having this diagonal regularity will still have this kind of regularity.

Comment: Yes actually you can, if you apply it term-wise. Consider the product of two such linear combinations of $C^k$, we can expand by multinomials, use $C^{n+m}=C^{m}$ to reduce exponents and accumulate term-wise exponent modulo $n$ we will be sure to stay with the same representation under multiplication. That the addition will stay is trivial.